# textread not working with .txt file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, text-files, text-parsing

In MATLAB: before I try to apply `textread` to the *.txt* file,  I have already split up the file from a large text file to smaller text files using a script which is successful in its execution and uses functions `fopen`, `fgetl`.

Large Text File -> Small Text File 1, Small Text File 2, Small Text File 3

Output of Small Text File 1:

```
Run Lat Long Time

2   1    13   3

2   3    3   3  

3   3    5   12
```

From the split up text file -- small text file 1 -- which is in column format, I apply `textread` and returns a mixture of random (scattered) data  from the text file (random sample of data from *col2* and *col3*).

In the code: the function is the basic:

```
[col1 col2] = textread('smallfile.txt', '%d %d');
```

Output Return:

```
3
12
13
5
```

Not what is in Col1 = `2 2 3`

I have tried to fix it by checking ANSI encoding and applying `rt` in my opening function.  But no success.

Comment: I cannot understand what's happening here. Could you improve your question, maybe post some code and examples of the actual and expected output?

Comment: I have update the question to be more clearer.

Answer (score 3):

You're reading only two numbers at a time with `textread`, instead of four. Try this:

```
[col1 col2, col3, col4] = textread('test.txt', '%d %d %d %d');
```

This yields:

```
col1 =

     2
     2
     3
```

like you wanted.

#### P.S

You can use the asterisk (`*`) in a field to ignore that field. For example, if you want to extract the first two columns and ignore the other two, you can do the following:

```
[col1, col2] = textread('test.txt', '%d %d %*d %*d');
```